# Proof concerning set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove: for any two sets $A$ and $B$ there exists a set $C$ such that: $A = (B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B).$

How would one prove this?
I noticed that there already is a post concerning this, but the answers given there are all false.

Comment: $C=A\Delta B$ is correct. Why do you say it is false?

Comment: it is correct, but why don't you explain it? Furthermore, I referred to some post conerning this question that got proposed by someone in my last post

Comment: I just want to understand how you can properly derive this...

Comment: If you are claiming that there is a post with incorrect answers, then you should provide a link. But the answers in this post look fine to me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864214/prove-or-disprove-that-for-any-two-sets-a-and-b-there-exists-a-set-c-such-that/3864242#comment7970317_3864242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That proposition is true. Let’s see why.

*Proof*: Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets. We define the set $C$ as $C =(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$. We can write $C$ more concisely using the definition of *symmetric difference*. In this case we write $C = A \Delta B$.

As you can easily check, the *symmetric difference* is associative, commutative and have some other nice properties such as $X \Delta \emptyset = X$ and $X \Delta X = \emptyset$ for any set $X$. (Just use the definition of $\Delta$).

Given this, we have the following.

$$\begin{align}
(B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B) \quad & = & B \Delta C & \\
& = &  B \Delta (A \Delta B) \\
& = & (A \Delta B) \Delta B & \quad \quad \text{$\Delta$ is commutative} \\
& = & A \Delta (B \Delta B) & \quad \quad \text{$\Delta$ is associative} \\
& = & A \Delta \emptyset & \quad \quad \text{$X \Delta X = \emptyset$} \\
& = & A & \quad \quad \text{$X \Delta \emptyset = X$}
\end{align}$$

Conclusion, given any sets $A$ and $B$, we found a set $C$ such that $A = (B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)$. This proves our claim. $\square$

Comment: just one question: How did you come up with the formula for C that fast?

Comment: It was not that fast nor obvious, but for searching it you can use a visual aid such as a Venn Diagram and from that you try to work out a formula for that set. Although Venn Diagrams are nice visual aids, they don’t substitute a rigorous proof. Therefore, every time you use a Venn Diagram to work with sets, you always have to proof at the end that your conclusions are tru.

Comment: So there is no strict analytical ways how one could come up with this formula for C?

Comment: Like manipulating the equation in order to obtain directly the formula for $C$?

Comment: yes, something like this.

Comment: I don’t if that is some algebraic way to do this. One way that comes to my mind would be using characteristic functions but it wouldn’t say that much either